# How to apply a value from one method to another?

Tags: java, methods

Cant set radius to count square: there're two methods, but how to force Java to count my square through radius that is random from `randomNumber()` ?

```
public class Figure {  

    public double randomNumber() {
        return Math.random() * 11;
    }
    public double circleArea () {
       return Math.PI*Math.pow(r,2); //how to assign a variable r in order to connect to randomNumber()??
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Figure figure = new Figure();
        System.out.println("r="+figure.randomNumber()+", s="+figure.circleArea());
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Few different ways. You need to choose what works best for your scenario:

You can call the method from where required.

```
public double circleArea () {
   return Math.PI*Math.pow(randomNumber(),2);
}
```

You can change the method to include a variable.

```
public double circleArea (double r) {
   return Math.PI*Math.pow(r,2);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Figure figure = new Figure();
    double r = figure.randomNumber();
    System.out.println("r=" + r + ", s=" + figure.circleArea(r));
}
```

Comment: in both ways I get different r for output-I mean from randomNumber() I get one value for r, from circleArea() I get the another value for r. Eventually, output is not correct coz square is counted with his own random radius.(
Seems like r is generated two times

Comment: You should not use both ways at once. If you use the second way, the value should be the same for `r`. Remember that you are generating random numbers, the output will be different each time you run the program.

Comment: `System.out.println("r="+figure.randomNumber()+", s="+figure.circleArea(r));` is different in my answer. Do not call the randomNumber function again.

Comment: can you write the whole programm how you think it should work?

Comment: man now I got it! Yes the problem was in System.out.println as you noticed. I generated r two times by my own) now I print only r instead of figure.randomNumber(). It works correct. Thank you!

Comment: If the answer worked then please accept the answer as the accepted answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is defining a private variable that holds the `r` value

```
public class Figure {
private double r;
public double randomNumber() {
    r = Math.random() * 11;
    return r;
}
public double circleArea () {
   return Math.PI*Math.pow(r,2); //how to assign a variable r in order to connect to randomNumber()??
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Figure figure = new Figure();
    System.out.println("r="+figure.randomNumber()+", s="+figure.circleArea());
}
```

Comment: Why private exactly?

Comment: I don't see any reason for `r` to be public since the field is accessible only within its own class.